# TSQL stuff for xml path and sub query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've to replace csv datas in column by correspondant id always in csv format

I've a problem with this query :

```
select t0.code , t0.categories, t0.departement, (
    SELECT Stuff((
        SELECT N', ' + CONVERT(varchar, id_categorie) FROM tcategories t1 WHERE t0.departement = t1.departement COLLATE French_CI_AI and categorie IN (t0.tcategories)  
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','varchar(max)'),1,1,N'')) as id_colonne  
FROM #codes_reductions t0 where categories is not null
```

Here is the result :

> code    |    categories    |   departement    |     id_colonne
>
> AIRSTREAM  | 'A','B','BA'  |    JMQ           |     NULL

If I replace 'and categorie IN (t0.tcategories)' by and categorie IN ('A','B','BA')  the query works good

Here is the result :

> code    |    categories    |   departement    |     id_colonne
>
> AIRSTREAM  | 'A','B','BA'  |    JMQ           |     128, 129, 260

I tryed to use COLLATE French_CI_AI on my column, but without success. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
... categorie IN (t0.tcategories) ....
```

The cause of your *problem* is that `categorie` column stores those values (`'A','B','BA'`) as a single value not as an array / list / table of values. So, SQL Server compares two strings thus `s1 IN (s2)` which is equivalent to `s1 = s2` => `A` IN (`'A','B','BA'`) <=> `A` = `'A','B','BA'`.

Example (note: double single quotes (`''`) are used to define an empty string while four single quotes (`''''`) are used to define a string with a single quote: `SELECT '''' --> '`):

```
DECLARE @categories VARCHAR(1000);

SET     @categories = '''A'',''B'',''BA'''
SELECT @categories AS ColA, CASE WHEN 'A' IN (@categories) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS Col2
/*
ColA         Col2
------------ -----
'A','B','BA' FALSE
*/
```

The solution on short term is to use one of following conditions:

```
C#1 (if categorie contains single quotes):  ... t0.tcategories LIKE '%' + categorie + '%' ....

C#2 (when categorie doesn't contains single quotes):  ... t0.tcategories LIKE '%''' + categorie + '''%' ....
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @categories VARCHAR(1000);

SET     @categories = '''A'',''B'',''BA'''
SELECT @categories AS ColA, CASE WHEN @categories LIKE '%''A''%' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS Col2
/*
ColA         Col2
------------ -----
'A','B','BA' TRUE
*/
```

Second note: this works when every *separate* value from `t0.tcategories` column doesn't includes single quote(s) (example: `'B'A'` / `'B''A'` ).

On medium/long term, you should store separately every single value from `tReduction.tCategories` column using another table :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ReductionCategory (
... pk ...,
ReductionCode INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.tReduction(ReductionCode), -- FK
CategoryCode INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.tCategories(CategoryCode) -- FK  
)
```

Thus, condition becomes

```
... categorie /*CategoryCode*/ 
IN (
    SELECT rc.CategoryCode FROM dbo.ReductionCategory rc 
    WHERE rc.ReductionCode = t0.ReductionCode
) ....
```

Comment: If you have any questions then feel free to ask.